# "Стоп майдан"

Tags: пунктуация

У нас во время украинского переворота везде были расклеены призывы "Стоп майдан". Именно так, без запятой. Скажите, нужна тут запятая или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПОЧИТАЕМ СЛОВАРЬ:

Стоп  машина! – междометие, команда для прекращения движения, работы.

Стоп, хватит ругаться  – приказ остановиться.

Говорил, говорил и вдруг – стоп – в функции сказуемого.

Сигнал стоп  - существительное в роли несогл. определения, стоп-сигнал – приложение.

ВЫБИРАЕМ ВАРИАНТ:

А) Стоп майдан! – похоже на «Не нужен майдан"! или  "Долой майдан!» – этот вариант предпочтительнее, в нем больше экспрессии;
Б) Стоп, майдан! – обращение с приказом остановиться.

Comment: Здесь явно не обращение к Майдану. Это все равно что обращаться к машине "Стоп, машина! Остановись, железяка!" или "Стоп, наводнение! Стоять! Куда пошло?". Это призыв "Остановить Майдан!".

Answer (score 2):

Ну если украинский "переворот", то у них и надо спрашивать.  Не хотелось бы так явно демонстрировать свои политические пристрастия, тем более, что они разные могут быть.
А что касается написания, то зависит от смысла, прежде всего - от того, к кому это стоп адресовано.
Если это *"Стоп Майдан!"* в значении "Останови Майдан!" то запятой, понятно, не надо.
А если к самому Майдану, то запятая, понятно, нужна, но стилистика несколько страннованта. Да и без восклицательного знака тоже как-то неуютно.
А если это что то вроде названия движения "Антимайдан", то тут можно спорить, *"Стопмайдан"* или *"Стоп-Майдан"*.

Короче, хорошо бы посмотреть на этот продукт пропагандистской мысли.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68578/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus--).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь *стоп* - междометие, означает команду для прекращения движения, работы. Только вот аналогичный пример - *Стоп машина!* - в разных словарях то с запятой ("Малый академический словарь"), то без ("Толковый словарь" Кузецова).

Comment: Междомение -допустим, но с глагольным значением. 
Только не ссылайтесь на Кузнецова по части пунктуации.  
  
"Стоп, машина!" - без запятой как-то и не смотрится. Вот если бы "стоп машину"...

Comment: А  как  междометие  может  стать  командой ?  Вира  и  майна  тоже  междометия ?

Comment: Да, вира и майна тоже междометия.

Answer (score 0):

Обыкновенное  неграмотное  написание. Общий  смысл  ясен  -  и  достаточно.  А  если  построено  по  шаблону  "стоп  машина"  то  и  в  грамотные  попадает.  Но  тогда  восклицательный  знак  нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается знаков препинания , то запятая для лозунгов такого типа абсолютно не требуется , - здесь просто выражено отрицательное отношение к конкретному явлению . Это выглядит приблизительно , как характерный эсэсэсэровскй лозунг "*Нет войне !*" . Восклицательный знак можно бы и поставить , но смысл восклицательного знака это усиление эмоции , так сказать , повышенный тон . Если то же самое произнести обычным тоном , то суть останется не изменённой .

Comment: Просьба не переходить на политику.

Comment: Каким  тоном  не  произнеси,  хоть  шёпотом,  восклицательный  знак  нужен,  т.к.  это  призыв,  лозунг,  команда.  Правила  пунктуации  требуют.

Comment: Если шёпотом, то не нужен.)))
Побудительные предложения не всегда бывают восклицательными.

Answer (score 0):

*Стоп* в этом выражении не междометье, а непереведённый английский глагол stop.
"Остановить (остановите) майдан!". Запятая не нужна.

Аналогично во французском словосочетании haute coutur (качественный пошив, высокое портновское искусство) прилагательное haute (*от*, *высокий*) воспринято как русский предлог *от*.
"От кого?" - "От кутюр."))))

Comment: По  аналогу  со  "стоп, машина"  междометием  считается  всё  выражение,  а  не  только  стоп.  Встречается  написание  как  с  запятой,  так  и  без  оной.