# Пунктуация: "Стоп наркотик"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая или, возможно, восклицательный знак между словами "стоп" и "наркотик"? Это название проекта по противодействию рекламе наркотиков.

Comment: Некоторые мнения можно посмотреть здесь: "Стоп майдан" https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd. И здесь: "Стоп, самострой!" Ставить ли запятую? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431693/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e.

Comment: Спасибо! Нашла ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Ответ Граммы.ру касается и вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу вопроса о запятой в выражении "Стоп самастрой!" я обратился к Грамме.ру, и вот, что они ответили.

Ответ Gramma.ru

Пунктуационное оформление сочетаний со словом **"стоп"** является неустойчивым. В словарях отмечается употребление **"стоп"** в качестве междометия "как команда для прекращения движения, остановки в значении стой, остановись" и в качестве сказуемого "для обозначения остановки, прекращения движения, работы". Во втором значении слово **"стоп"** не предусматривает возможность распространения другими словами, **ср.: Прохор сразу - стоп - снял шапку и перекрестился (Шишков, Угрюм-река).**

Первоначально существительное в Им. п., стоящее после слова **"стоп"**, рассматривалось только как обращение, поэтому регулярно отделялось запятой. Это касается и фразы **"Стоп машина",** которая писалась с запятой: **"Стоп, машина!",** так как это было командой, обращенной машинному отделению **(метонимически - "машина"). (Ср. аналогичное употребление: Я не преувеличиваю, и мне не изменяет память: в тот момент, когда сцена была сыграна и снята, Лариса с криком «Стоп, камера!» [Ю. И. Визбор. Когда все были вместе (1980-1983)].)** В связи с переосмыслением значения фразы и ее фразеологизацией она стала писаться без запятой. Однако на другие случаи употребления существительных в Им. п. после слова **"стоп"** это оформление должно распространяться автоматически. Таким образом, среди предложенных Вами вариантов правильным следует признать вариант **"Стоп, самострой!".**

**Слово "стоп"** может распространяться и существительным в Д. п. Например: **...Дать бы красный / по всей планете: / Стоп войне! Осторожно - / дети! (Ю. Друнина. Ты рядом. М., 1964. С. 93).** Возможно, эта возможность появилась под влиянием близкой по значению конструкции со словом "нет", **ср.: Стоп войне / Нет войне.  Исходя из этого, можно допустить оформление конструкции "Стоп самострою!".**

Comment: Честно говоря, меня это только запутало. Все-таки они рекомендуют ставить запятую? Или допускают оба варианта? (первый абзац)

Comment: Здесь две полезные, наряду с правильной (стоп, наркотик), тоже правильные рекомендации написания: (1) стоп наркотику и (2) стоп — наркотик!

Comment: .@Угла, они говорят о том, что запятая должна стоять, и фразеологизм "Стоп машина"  не должен вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: В отличие от "стоп-машины" (только команда, обращение к тем, кто управляет "машиной") здесь возможны разные смыслы: а) _обращение к наркотику_ (мол, врёшь, наркотик, не пройдёшь - тогда запятая); б) _обращение к людям_ (обратите внимание: это наркотик, а не лекарство; остановитесь - не проходите мимо открытого распространения наркотиков). Во втором случае возможны двоеточие и тире.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Серж, хорошо бы также поместить этот ответ Gramma.ru под вопросом о самострое.

Comment: Уже разместил..